# Multiple Kinect

Tags: kinect, openni-kinect, pointcloud-to-laserscan, openni-node, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am trying to use two kinects, one to perform human tracking and object recognition, and one to navigate (using pointcloud to laserscan).

I modified the openni_node.launch with two nodes and I adjusted the kinect_frames.launch.
Both kinect publish the rgb image, but just one (apparently randomly) publishes the pointcloud.

Here are the files I modified

openni_node.launch

```
<launch>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg if="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="xterm -rv -e gdb -ex run -args"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value=""/>
  <node pkg="openni_camera" type="openni_node" name="openni_node1" output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
    <!--param name="topic" value="first" /-->
    <!--param name="device_id" value="2@3" --> <!-- this line uses device on usb bus 2 and addres 3 -->
    <param name="device_id" value="A00366A12990044A"/> <!-- this line uses device with given serial number -->

    <!--param name="device_id" value="#1" /-->

    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find openni_camera)/info/openni_params.yaml" />
    <param name="rgb_frame_id" value="/openni_rgb_optical_frame" />
    <param name="depth_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_optical_frame" />
    <param name="use_indices" value="false" />
    <param name="depth_registration" value="true" />
    <param name="image_mode" value="2" />
    <param name="depth_mode" value="2" />
    <param name="debayering" value="2" />
    <param name="depth_time_offset" value="0" />
    <param name="image_time_offset" value="0" />
  </node>
    <node pkg="openni_camera" type="openni_node" name="openni_node2" output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
    <!--param name="topic" value="first" /-->
    <param name="device_id" value="A00363A00048052A"/>

    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find openni_camera)/info/openni_params.yaml" />
    <remap from="camera" to="camera_2"/>
    <param name="rgb_frame_id" value="/openni_rgb_optical_frame_2" />
    <param name="depth_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_optical_frame_2" />
    <param name="use_indices" value="false" />
    <param name="depth_registration" value="true" />
    <param name="image_mode" value="2" />
    <param name="depth_mode" value="2" />
    <param name="debayering" value="2" />
    <param name="depth_time_offset" value="0" />
    <param name="image_time_offset" value="0" />
  </node>
  <include file="$(find openni_camera)/launch/kinect_frames.launch"/>
</launch>
```

kinect_frames.launch

```
<launch>
<!--  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_openni" args="-0.04 0 0 1.57 -1.57 0 /base_link /openni_camera 100" />  -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_fake_laser" args="-0.155 -0.14 0.19 -1.57 0 0  /base_link /base_laser 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link" args="0.02 0 0 -3.14 0 0 /openni_camera /openni_depth_frame 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link1" args="0.04 0 0 -3.14 0 0 /openni_camera /openni_rgb_frame 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link2" args="0 0 0 3.14 0 0 /openni_depth_frame /openni_depth_optical_frame  100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link3" args="0 0 0 3.14 0 0 /openni_rgb_frame /openni_rgb_optical_frame 100" />

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link0_2" args="-0.155 -0.14 0.19 3.14 0 -1.57 /base_link /openni_camera_2 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link_2" args="0.02 0 0 -3.14 0 0 /openni_camera_2 /openni_depth_frame_2 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link1_2" args="0.04 0 0 -3.14 0 0 /openni_camera_2 /openni_rgb_frame_2 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link2_2" args="0 0 0 3.14 0 0 /openni_depth_frame_2 /openni_depth_optical_frame_2  100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_base_link3_2" args="0 0 0 3.14 0 0 /openni_rgb_frame_2 /openni_rgb_optical_frame_2 100" />

</launch>
```

Thank you so much for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11547/multiple-kinect/) by [Lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/293/lorenzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2011-10-14**:
I was also trying this yesterday and was experiencing a similar problem. I haven't had a lot of time to play around with it, but I'll keep you updated If I find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the issue is that both nodes are publishing to the same topic simultaneously. Since the topic name of each node is not a parameter, you cannot change the topic in the standard way. Instead, you must use the following in your launch file:

```
<node pkg="openni_camera" type="openni_node" name="openni_node1" output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
   <remap from="camera/depth/points" to="camera/depth/points1" />
   ...
</node>

<node pkg="openni_camera" type="openni_node" name="openni_node2" output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
   <remap from="camera/depth/points" to="camera/depth/points2" />
   ...
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-30**:
I'm a little skeptical since "openni_node" in rxgraph doesn't publish any topic regarding images even under default config. But when I tried modifying kinect.launch which publishes camera/depth/**, program even got stuck in the middle and didn't progress. .launch file -> http://pastebin.com/C3cgmA4w

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-30**:
Thanks I tried but didn't work. Neither topic was published it seemed. .launch file I used -> http://pastebin.com/HbLhy5wF

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at the [source](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/openni_camera/html/openni__device__kinect_8h_source.html) for the openni_camera device_kinect.h you'll see that the kinect doesn't support hardware synchronization.

Based on this, I think you might get interference if the cameras are pointed towards the same area. To solve this in software, you might have to devise a way of intermittently shutting the IR light projector off for alternating sensors (probably by hacking the drivers somehow?), settling for half the framerate (at best). You could make an experiment by connecting the cameras to separate computers and checking what results you get in the overlapping fov.

If the sensors never look at the same space, perhaps there is a way to force them to work simultaneously anyway. I hope you find an answer :)

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) with karma: 465 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2